# How to add an image to an item in a dojo/dnd/Source

Tags: dojo, dojo-dnd

I've create a dnd solution, with a source and target location.  Right now the drag is bi-directional, I would like to have it be one-direction target to source.  Then from the source add a image to each item (a delete icon), so that the users can then click the icon and send the record back to the correct target.

Part 1, I am trying to understand how to make the dnd one-directional and Part 2, how do I add an image to each item.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are events which handles this in the dnd module.

as for 'part1', see this http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/dnd.html#id6 and set  `is'Source : false` on the target which should only be a target.

and with 'part2' go to http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/dnd.html#id8 and read about 'onDrop'. If overloading that function in your 'target-only' source, you will gain access to the nodes which is being dropped.

```
 onDrop: function(source, nodes, copy) {
    dojo.forEach(nodes, function(node) {
       node.innerHTML += "<button title=Delete> X </button>";
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got working.

```
dojo.connect(selectedInstructions, "onDndDrop", instructions.addDeleteButton);

addDeleteButton: function (source, nodes, copy, target) {
    if (source != target) {
        dojo.forEach(nodes, function(node) {
            var instructionId = node.getAttribute("id");
            var oImg = document.createElement("img");
            oImg.setAttribute('src', 'images/delete.png');
            oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'Remove');
            oImg.setAttribute('class', 'remove_instruction');
            oImg.setAttribute('onClick', "javascript:instructions.removeInstruction('" + instructionId + "')");
            document.getElementById(instructionId).appendChild(oImg); 
        });
    }
},
```

I then tried to get `on` to work, since `connect` is being depreciated, but I didn't appear to have much luck.  I will have to come back to it at a later date, as I am on a time crunch right now to get this code out.

```
on(selectedInstructions, "onDrop", instructions.addDeleteButton);
aspect.after(selectedInstructions, "onDrop", instructions.addDeleteButton);
```

Wish the Dojo documentation was better.  Thanks goodness for the community and it's support though.

Comment: I think it would be perfectly applicable, using either one  - one or aspect. you may however want to `hitch` into `instructions` to get the correct scope such as : `aspect.after(selectedInstructions, "onDrop", lang.hitch(instructions, 'addDeleteButton');`. As for `.on`, it should work - try removing 'on' prefix though - but its design is for DOMEvent mainly imho